# aws-cdk cli version | Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-cdk, ubuntu-20.04

Is there any way to update your aws-cdk version on a Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS? Tried to run these commands:

```
sudo npm uninstall aws-cdk
Output:
up to date, audited 1 package in 76ms

found 0 vulnerabilities

sudo npm uninstall -g aws-cdk
Output:
removed 1 package, and audited 1 package in 105ms

found 0 vulnerabilities

cdk --version
Output:
2.18.0 (build 75c90fa)

npm config list
Output:
; node bin location = /usr/bin/node
; node version = v16.17.0
; npm local prefix = /home/dev
; npm version = 8.15.0
; cwd = /home/dev
; HOME = /home/dev
; Run `npm config ls -l` to show all defaults.

npm list
Output:
/home/dev
└── (empty)

npm list -g
Output:
/usr/lib
├── corepack@0.12.1
├── jslint@0.12.1
├── npm@8.15.0
└── typescript@4.6.3

sudo npm install -g aws-cdk
Output:
added 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 1s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

But running the `uninstall` does not actually uninstall the aws-cdk. Because I tried to even run the `cdk --version` and it prints out `2.18.0 (build 75c90fa)`. Also restarted the machine, I'm having the same issue of not being able to update my cdk cli.

Running the command `which cdk` gives me a result of: `/usr/local/bin/cdk`.

Here's my environment version:

- npm: 8.15.0
- node: v16.17.0
- cdk: 2.18.0 (build 75c90fa)
- Ubuntu: 20.04.5 LTS

Comment: After uninstalling it with `-g`: add the output of `npm config list`, `npm list` and `npm list -g`. Do not run `install/uninstall` without `-g`, this is definitely wrong.

Comment: Hello, I already added those things that you asked :)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this I'm afraid.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your help :) I tried to remove all (`npm`, `nodejs`, `aws-cdk`) by using the `rm -rf`. And re-install it all :)